# Determine the graph of an absolute value function

Tags: absolute-value

How do I know what |x-1| = 1 look like on a graph without a graph calculator.

Is this the proper way of writing it:

$$
\begin{gathered}\begin{gathered}|x-1|=|y|\\ |y|=\begin{cases}y,&y\geqslant 0\\ -y&y<0\\ &\end{cases} \end{gathered} \\ \end{gathered} 
$$

Or

$$
|x-1|=1=\begin{cases}x=2&x\geqslant 0\\ -\left( x-1\right)  =1&x<0\\ &\end{cases}
$$

Or

$$
|x-1|=\begin{cases}
x-1, \quad x \geq 1\\[2ex]
1-x, \quad x<1
\end{cases}
$$

I was told this is the way to write it, but what happens to the ” = 1”? Why do we have x≥1 and x<1?
I just wanted to write it in terms of cases, but I don't know how to determine how it looks like on a graph from there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The equation $|x-1|=1$ has two solutions: $x=0$ and $x=2$. If you really want to graph $y$ as a function of $x$ (which seems a bit odd), then it is just two vertical lines at $x=0$ and $x=2$.